# Is there a web application that tracks visitors to a specific web page?

Tags: webapp-rec, analytics, tracking

I would like a web app that tracks visitors to a certain web page of a big website. i.e. a page in TMZ or my YouTube channel. I would also like to be able to track whether they came from a link or inputted the url manually. Is there a tool like that?

Edit: I don't own the webpage so I have no access to the source code.

Edit 2: The exact reason I need it is because I'm making a puzzle with a giveaway for a forum I frequent, and it would be an extra measure to detect leakage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you own the website then Google Analytics is the way to go.

If you don't own the website then it'll be a lot trickier. You can use something like Alexa ranks to track traffic generically, but that won't tell you anything about specific traffic.

Or if you'd rather track the traffic you are sending to that page from your link I'd suggest linking to the page from a [bit.ly](https://bitly.com/) link which will let you track clicks on your specific link.

Comment: bit.ly could work too, but I'm also looking for whether they came from a link or just inputted the url in manually. Is there another link shortening service with that feature?

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics will work on your youtube channel, not sure about your TMZ page though.

Setting up Google Analytics on your Brand Channel

1. Sign up for a Google Analytics account at http://www.google.com/analytics.
2. If you have an existing Google Analytics login, you may create a new account by selecting “Create New Account” in the drop-down on the top right of the page. While it is possible to create a new profile within an existing account by selecting “Add New Profile”, we recommend creating a new account so that the data from your YouTube channel does not impact the data summaries from your other websites.
3. Locate your Google Analytics Profile ID, which takes the form of "UA-123123-1". This can be found while in the Overview of the account, listed with the website profiles.
4. Log into your YouTube account. Click on "My Channel" in the top right. Go to "Channel settings" above featured video area. Go to "Info and Settings tab (second tab). Add your google analytics ID in the appropriate form field (last one). Save by clicking "Done Editing".
5. Once you save your changes, you should allow up to 24 hours for data to appear in your account. If you wait 24 hours and still don't see any data, please check the Troubleshooter for common tracking setup mistakes.
6. (Optional) So that your YouTube rep may assist you if you have any questions related to your account, we request that you grant access to brandchanneltracking@gmail.com. For instructions on adding users, please refer to the Analytics Help section on user access.

from http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=147619

Answer (score 0):

If you don't own the page, then are you really entitled to the date?

Surely if you are entitled to it, then the owner would happily add code that you ask them to add?   In which case, as the others said, Google Analytics is a good option.